# Problem with start GETH service

Tags: systemctl

I have problem with starting a systemd service of `geth`.

This is the service specification `geth.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Geth

[Service]
Type=simple
User=eth
Restart=always
RestartSec=12
ExecStart=/home/eth/starteth.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This is the `starteth.sh` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
geth --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcport "9820" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

And I get error when start service and check status

```
root@server:~# sudo systemctl start geth
root@server:~# sudo systemctl status geth
● geth.service - Geth
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/geth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-06-16 22:02:51 CEST; 3s ago
  Process: 19295 ExecStart=/home/eth/starteth.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 19295 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Edit: OS is Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 1):

The `starteth.sh` is a shell script that expects to find an executable named `geth` somewhere in `$PATH`, but most likely it cannot be found as the `$PATH` used by systemd is quite minimal. Is there such a file anywhere? Try `locate geth` or `find / -name geth` to find it. Then prefix the `geth` in `starteth.sh` with the correct absolute path.

Comment: some issue. i dont know what to make more...

Comment: `starteth.sh` is looking for `/bin/geth`, `/usr/bin/geth` and/or `/usr/local/bin/geth`, but is not finding it. Do you have `/home/eth/geth`? If yes, then change the 2nd line of `starteth.sh` from `geth --syncmode ...` to `/home/eth/geth --syncmode ...`.

Answer (score 0):

as the answer mentioned above to locate geth   so yes file geth is present /usr/bin/geth

but sill the error is comming

× geth.service - Ethereum go client
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/geth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-04-26 13:17:37 UTC; 2min 46s ago
Process: 2862 ExecStart=/usr/bin/geth --networkid 9988 --datadir /opt/ethpoa2/node1/data --port 30303 --ipcdisable >
Main PID: 2862 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
CPU: 1ms

Apr 26 13:17:37 ip-172-31-87-252 systemd[1]: geth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 26 13:17:37 ip-172-31-87-252 systemd[1]: geth.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 26 13:17:37 ip-172-31-87-252 systemd[1]: Stopped Ethereum go client.
Apr 26 13:17:37 ip-172-31-87-252 systemd[1]: geth.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 26 13:17:37 ip-172-31-87-252 systemd[1]: geth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 26 13:17:37 ip-172-31-87-252 systemd[1]: Failed to start Ethereum go client.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/443666)